# Does anyone have a complete list of Demons that Shiva Killed and a list of Demons who worshiped Shiva?

Tags: shiva, rakshasa

In my attempt to understand the Gods(their Tatvarth), I wanted to know what demonic tendencies were not approved by Shiva and what demonic tendencies worshiped Shiva.
We all know some of the demons, but I wanted to compile a complete list.

Comment: Shiva , Skanda Puranas can give a better list.  It is better to read the Puranas for yourself so that an exhaustive list of demons killed by Shiva.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because list like questions are off topic here...

Comment: @YDS I don't see that in Meta. Can you link me to it?